# convert action<> lambda to full delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have the following code that uses a lambda:

```
this.Notify(action: listener => listener.OnAccelerometersChanged(x, y, z));
```

action parameter is of type `Action<IMyInterface>`.

I would like to convert this lambda to a full delegate because under Xamarin.iOS, as this method is called very often, the lambda is compiled every time and the number of objects in memory increment endlessly.

So I would like to get rid of the lambda in favor of a method that is compiled once.

Is it possible?

What would be its signature?

EDIT: The use of 'full delegate' comes from the takeaways of [this video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/xamarin-xamarin-developer-summit-2019/your-xamarin-application-is-probably-leaking-memory-and-you-dont-know-it).

EDIT 2: Here is the method:

```
private void NotifyNewAccelerometerValues(double x, double y, double z)
{
    this.Notify(action: listener => listener.OnAccelerometersChanged(x, y, z));
    ...
}
```

EDIT 3: Here is the whole class:

```
using RTE.Technologies.CommonServices.Services;
using RTE.Technologies.SystemTools.Log;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RTE.Technologies.CommonServices
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the IOS implementation of the <see cref="IAccelerometerService"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class AccelerometerService : IOSServiceNotifier<IAccelerometerListener>, IAccelerometerService
    {
        /// <summary> The <see cref="AccelerometerListener"/> instance. </summary>
        private readonly AccelerometerListener accelerometerListener;

        /// <summary> The <see cref="AutoResetEvent"/> for stop detection. </summary>
        private readonly AutoResetEvent stopDetectionEvent = new AutoResetEvent(initialState: false);

        /// <summary> The background <see cref="Task"/> for stop detection. </summary>
        private readonly Task accelerometerServiceTask;

        /// <summary> A value indicating whether if the waiting operation has been aborted. </summary>
        private volatile bool abort;

        /// <summary> The duration threshold. </summary>
        private TimeSpan durationThreshold = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value: 30d);

        /// <summary> The movement threshold. </summary>
        private double movementThreshold = 1d;

        /// <summary> A value indicating whether if a parameter has changed. </summary>
        private volatile bool parameterHasChanged;

        /// <summary> A value indicating whether if a stop is waiting. </summary>
        private volatile bool waitingStop;

        /// <summary> A value indicating whether if a move has been detected. </summary>
        private volatile bool isMoving = true;
        public AccelerometerService(Logger logger) : base(logger)
        {
            this.accelerometerListener = new AccelerometerListener(service: this);
            this.accelerometerServiceTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(action: this.CheckAccelerometerStopTimeout, creationOptions: TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds or removes handler on <see cref="OnMoveDetectedEvent"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<MoveDetectionEventArgs> OnMoveDetected
        {
            add { this.OnMoveDetectedEvent += value; }
            remove { this.OnMoveDetectedEvent -= value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds or removes handler on <see cref="OnAccelerationChangedEvent"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<AccelerometerValuesEventArgs> OnAccelerationChanged
        {
            add { this.OnAccelerationChangedEvent += value; }
            remove { this.OnAccelerationChangedEvent -= value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when a move has been detected.
        /// </summary>
        private event EventHandler<MoveDetectionEventArgs> OnMoveDetectedEvent;

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when acceleration has changed.
        /// </summary>
        private event EventHandler<AccelerometerValuesEventArgs> OnAccelerationChangedEvent;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the movement threshold.
        /// </summary>
        public double MovementThreshold
        {
            get
            {
                return this.movementThreshold;
            }

            set
            {
                if (Math.Abs(value: value - this.movementThreshold) > 0.00001d)
                {
                    this.parameterHasChanged = true;
                    this.movementThreshold = value;

                    this.stopDetectionEvent.Set();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the duration threshold.
        /// </summary>
        public TimeSpan DurationThreshold
        {
            get
            {
                return this.durationThreshold;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.durationThreshold != value)
                {
                    this.parameterHasChanged = true;
                    this.durationThreshold = value;

                    this.stopDetectionEvent.Set();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates acceleration value in each axis.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The acceleration on X.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The acceleration on Y.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The acceleration on Z.</param>
        internal void UpdateValues(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            this.CheckMovement(x, y, z);

            this.NotifyNewAccelerometerValues(x, y, z);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">True if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.IsDisposed)
            {
                this.abort = true;
                if (disposing)
                {
                    this.stopDetectionEvent.Set();
                    this.accelerometerServiceTask.Wait(timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value: 20d));
                    this.stopDetectionEvent.Dispose();
                    this.accelerometerListener?.Dispose();
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing: disposing);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies that moving state has changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="moving"></param>
        private void OnMovingChanged(bool moving)
        {
            if (moving != this.isMoving)
            {
                this.isMoving = moving;

                this.Notify(action: MovingAction(moving));
                this.OnMoveDetectedEvent?.Invoke(sender: this, e: new MoveDetectionEventArgs(isMoving: moving));
            }
        }

        private static Action<IAccelerometerListener> MovingAction(bool moving)
        {
            return listener => listener.OnMovingChanged(moving);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies the accelerometers new values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The acceleration on X.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The acceleration on Y.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The acceleration on Z.</param>
        private void NotifyNewAccelerometerValues(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            this.Notify(action: listener => listener.OnAccelerometersChanged(x, y, z));
            this.OnAccelerationChangedEvent?.Invoke(sender: this, e: new AccelerometerValuesEventArgs(x: x, y: y, z: z));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks movement detection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The accelerometer value on X.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The accelerometer value on Y.</param>
        /// <param name="z">The accelerometer value on Z.</param>
        private void CheckMovement(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            double vector = Math.Sqrt(d: (x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
            if (vector > 10 - this.movementThreshold && vector < 10 + this.movementThreshold)
            {
                // Accelerometers don't detect movement.
                if (this.isMoving && !this.waitingStop)
                {
                    // Starts waiting accelerometers timeout.
                    this.waitingStop = true;
                    this.stopDetectionEvent.Set();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Accelerometers detect movement.
                if (this.waitingStop)
                {
                    this.waitingStop = false;
                    this.stopDetectionEvent.Set();
                }

                if (!this.isMoving)
                {
                    // Stops waiting accelerometers timeout.
                    this.Logger.Write(logMessage: "Accelerometers detect a movement");
                    this.OnMovingChanged(moving: true);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks for stop in background.
        /// </summary>
        private void CheckAccelerometerStopTimeout()
        {
            this.Logger.Write(logMessage: "Start background stop checking");
            TimeSpan timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;

            while (!this.abort)
            {
                bool fromTimeout = !this.stopDetectionEvent.WaitOne(timeout: timeout);
                if (this.abort)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (this.parameterHasChanged)
                {
                    this.Logger.Write(logMessage: "Stop detection parameters have changed. Restart detection");
                    this.parameterHasChanged = this.waitingStop = false;
                    this.OnMovingChanged(moving: true);
                    timeout = this.durationThreshold;
                }
                else if (!fromTimeout)
                {
                    // The event has been set. Change timeout value.
                    timeout = this.waitingStop ? this.durationThreshold : Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
                }
                else
                {
                    // A timeout occurs. Check timeout reason.
                    if (this.isMoving && this.waitingStop)
                    {
                        // The accelerometer timeout occurs.
                        this.Logger.Write(logMessage: "The accelerometer detects a stop.");
                        this.waitingStop = false;
                        this.OnMovingChanged(moving: false);
                        timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value: this.durationThreshold.TotalSeconds * 5);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 4 : Here is the `Notify` implementation

```
protected void Notify(Action<TServiceListener> action)
{
    lock (this.Locker)
    {
        // Removed predicate used with RemoveAll to avoid memory leaks
        foreach (TServiceListener listener in this.Listeners)
        {
            if (listener == null)
            {
                this.listeners.Remove(listener);
            }
        }

        // Removed the linq expression to avoid leaks
        foreach (TServiceListener listener in this.listeners)
        {
            if (listener == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // using a cache to avoid string being created everytime.
            if (!listenersNameCache.TryGetValue(listener, out string name))
            {
                name = listener.GetType().Name;
                this.listenersNameCache.Add(listener, name);
            }

            string errorMessage = string.Format(provider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format: "Can't notify service update to listener {0}", args: name);

            // Avoid using lambda expression in a call to ManageExpession by ducplicating the code.
            try
            {
                action(obj: listener);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value: errorMessage))
                {
                    this.logger.WriteException(
                        exception: exception,
                        severity: SeverityLevel.Error,
                        logMessage: errorMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.logger.FormatException(
                        exception: exception,
                        severity: SeverityLevel.Error,
                        logMessageFormat: "An error occurs during call {0}",
                        args: nameof(this.Notify));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "full" delegate? How do you know it is "compiled every time"?  How do you know this particular lambda is the cause of "the number of objects in memory increment endlessly"?

Comment: because I have used the Xamarin profiler and I can see it ten thousands of time in memory.

Comment: A "lambda" is the name for the syntax `stuff => otherStuff`. The lambda syntax can mean different things in different contexts. In this context, it is compiled to a delegate. What you have there is therefore a "full delegate" (which is compiled at compile-time), so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Presumably the problem is that you are calling `Notify` a lot, and it's having to allocate a new display class to capture those `x`, `y` and `z` variables?

Comment: That's probably the case. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Can you share the whole method, or even the whole class? Where do `x`, `y` and `z` come from? Do they change every time you call `Notify`?

Comment: An `Action<X>` is a delegate, which can be assigned to any void method that takes in a single argument of type `X`. The question is where do the `x, y, z` variables are coming from.

Comment: I have added the method, the x, y, and z values are coming from the outside method

Comment: Can you post the full class please? Including the code which calls `NotifyNewAccelerometerValues`, and the code which defines `Notify`

Comment: You've already asked similar question... What happened with it?

Comment: Could you include the definition of `Notify`, please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76653340/caching-an-action-lambda 8 days ago

Comment: Added the **Notify** code. @Selvin It happened that I don't like people giving me lessons. They were not considering that everyone could be a newbie

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer

Comment: @OlivierMATROT In fairness we had to ask exactly the same questions on this version of your question, and only when you provided the answers were we able to help...

Comment: @canton7 Maybe, but to me, the first answer by JonasH seems to have been possible without all the code.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT I mean, there are many things we could have thrown at the wall, but most aren't applicable. We don't know which are applicable until we know more details about what you're doing. I could have written 5 different answers which *might* have been relevant based on your initial question, but you'd just have complained that "this isn't relevant" :D

Comment: [simple object pool](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YVR8vv) ... basically the same example as I posted as comment last time you've asked but with object pool (you can try to add `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` to `Action<IAccelerometerListener> Create(int x, int y, int z)` to test if it would have better performance)

Comment: @Selvin That will remove the display object allocation, but not the delegate instance allocation

Comment: Which code or call allocates delegate? In my code delegate is just a method reference...

Comment: Does return statement wraps it into delegate?

Comment: @Selvin `Action<T>` is a reference type. When you do `Action<T> x = ...`, you need to allocate a new instance of `Action<T>`. In your code, `return item.Call;` is shorthand for `return new Action<T>(item.Call)`. When used with a lambda, the compiler will cache the generated `Action<T>` when it can, but it won't in your case.

Comment: I mean action... Even if... You may create field of type action and assign it to call only once and return it instead

Comment: Fixed :D (I would post another snippet but it just overrides) **canton7's comments are about commented now code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you need to allocate a new class to capture the `x`, `y` and `z` variables (and then allocate a new delegate instance to point to a method on this new class).

To only way to avoid this is to avoid capturing these variables. One way to do this is tweaking the signature of `Notify` to accept a "state" parameter, which it passes to `action`:

```
protected void Notify<TState>(Action<TServiceListener, TState> action, TState state)
{
    ...
    action(obj: listener, state: state);
}
```

Then you can declare a *struct* type which captures `x`, `y` and `z`:

```
private record struct Accelerations(double X, double Y, double Z);
```

And you can use this to explicitly capture these variables:

```
private void NotifyNewAccelerometerValues(double x, double y, double z)
{
    var accelerations = new Accelerations(x, y, z);
    this.Notify(action: static (listener, state) => listener.OnAccelerometersChanged(state.X, state.Y, state.Z), state: accelerations);
    ...
}
```

(Note the use of a `static` lambda to ensure that we don't accidentally capture anything).

The `(listener, state) => listener.OnAccelerometersChanged(state.X, state.Y, state.Z)` lambda now doesn't capture anything from its surrounding scope (everything it accesses is passed in as a parameter). Therefore the compiler doesn't need to generate an extra class to capture anything, which also means that it can create the delegate instance once and cache it.

Alternatively, you can use a ValueTuple rather than an explicit type:

```
private void NotifyNewAccelerometerValues(double x, double y, double z)
{
    this.Notify(action: static (listener, state) => listener.OnAccelerometersChanged(state.x, state.y, state.z), state: (x, y, z));
    ...
}
```

(The runtime uses this pattern in e.g. [`string.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=net-7.0) and to a lesser extent in [`SynchronizationContext.Post`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post?view=net-7.0))

Comment: Very interesting. I try that now.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT hmm, [speed and allocations depends on runtime used](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/2ded2ecc464c4f086117941a11ed3802) it would be nice to try benchamerk on real device

Comment: @Selvin Nice! I'm shocked that ValueTuple is so much slower -- there must be something wrong there

Comment: Same here I was expected to valuetuple would be better than struct

Comment: Looks like the difference is only when using `int` (not `double` as OP does above), and is fixed in the latest .NET 8 preview

Answer (score 0):

> `listener => listener.OnAccelerometersChanged(x, y, z)`

This is a lambda, the compiler will figure out that the type of this lambda is `Action<IMyInterface>` and essentially lower this into a class:

```
public class MyHiddenClass{
    double X; double Y; double Z;
    public MyHiddenClass(double x, double y, double z) => (X, Y, Z) = (x, y, z);
    public void Method(IMyInterface listener) => listener.OnAccelerometersChanged(X, Y, Z);
}
```

So the lambda should only ever be compiled *once*. However, since the lambda is capturing variables it has to create a new object each time your method is called.

Normally this should not be a huge problem, since the object is small, and should presumably be very short lived. If you see a large increase in object count you may have a memory leak that you need to investigate. Your `Notify` method sounds like some kind of event registration method, and registering events without removing them is a common source of memory leaks.

If you absolutely want to avoid allocations you could try storing your x/y/z values as fields in a object that is reused, and use a method on this object instead of a lambda. I believe that this *may* avoid allocations since it avoids capturing variables, but I'm not ceirtan.

Comment: I will try an approach with instance fields, and then  probably mark this response as the accepted answer. There are Garbage Collection issues on Xamarin.iOS. There are explained in the video.